# When connecting one Cloud app to another Cloud app, is SSL required?

Tags: api, security, ssl, cloud

I apologize if I am asking something too obvious, but I as understand SSL should be used when making API calls to remote apps. This particularly important if you are using a password or API key in the calls so networking sniffing doesn't reveal the details.

Having said that, if I have a Cloud-hosted app, e.g. AWS hosted PHP script, that makes a call to a MongoDB database hosted by a third-party provider e.g. ObjectRocket, do I need SSL between the two?

Secondly, as I understand if both the apps are hosted on the same infrastructure, e.g. Heroku (which AWS-based) and a third-party MongoDB provider (if they use AWS of the same region) then SSL is redundant when connecting from a Heroku-hosted app to the the database as AWS will prevent networking sniffing.

Thank you for your help. I appreciate anyone who can provide some fundamental information here.